# Processing Zip files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create zip file only in memory in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532502/how-to-create-zip-file-only-in-memory-in-ruby)

Is anybody aware of a open source Ruby library that allows the user to process zip file entries in memory? i.e. without writing them to disk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I'm using [rubyzip library](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/). You can do something like this:

```
Zip::ZipFile.foreach(file) do |entry|
    istream = entry.get_input_stream
    data = istream.read
    #...
end
```