# How to create zip file only in memory in ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zip, rubyzip

I want to create a zip file of all HTML files in a given directory. The zip will be sent as an attachment via email along with the rest of the files from the directory. All email clients I tried so far have trouble reading an email if any attachment is a HTML file, if I send from pony. So I thought I'd zip them.

Is there any way to **zip** the HTML **files on the fly** but really **only in the memory**, without using any temp files on **Windows platform**? Preferably not using any external program?

If I understood right, both methods described in:

- http://info.michael-simons.eu/2008/01/21/using-rubyzip-to-create-zip-files-on-the-fly/ or
- http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html

are using some kind of temp file.

Comment: Why is a temp file undesirable? It's common to use them behind the scenes for temporary storage.

Comment: It is an option to use temp file if I cannot do it only in memory. It's ok to use temp file but I prefer not to.

Comment: The reason why a temp file is advantageous is in the case that the archive grows big enough to impact RAM. Spooling to a temp file will keep the machine running longer since it's a lot less likely to consume all the available disk space than it is to consume all available RAM. If you are on a machine with little free RAM give serious consideration to the temp file.

Comment: It's more the other way around. The zip will contain mostly only two small HTML files. So I thought it would easier and faster to do everything in memory.

Comment: For a small zip it will be marginally faster after you factor in buffering. I doubt you'd notice much difference.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But the question is... is it possible to zip file only in memory? It's more about my curiosity now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate zip file without saving to the disk with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405921/how-can-i-generate-zip-file-without-saving-to-the-disk-with-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought maybe you could use a StringIO object to write to, but it looks like the ZipOutputStream class insists on opening a temporary file.

If you don't mind calling an external program, standard linux zip can be told to send otuput to stdout instead of a file by using "-" instead of a filename.  So just collect the output into a variable then do whatever you like with it.

```
zipdata = %x(zip -q - *.html)
```

I don't think this is going to be an efficiency gain over just using a temporary file, but you'd have to measure it to be sure.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention that I am on windows. I like your approach though.