# ftp import zip file with csv data, getting "string contains null byte"

Tags: ruby, csv, ftp, ruby-on-rails-4, zip

I'm importing zip files **through ftp** like this

```
files = []
Net::FTP.open(SERVER_DOMAIN) do |ftp|
  ftp.passive = true
  ftp.login(FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD)
  day_range = (Time.now - DAY_RANGE.hours)..Time.now
  file_names = ftp.nlst
  file_names.each do |file_name|
    if day_range.cover?(ftp.mtime(file_name))
      file = ftp.getbinaryfile(file_name,nil, blocksize=1024)
      files << file
    end
  end
end
files
```

and then I'm passing each file into this block.

```
def unzip file
# I've tried putting `file`, which is really just content, into a `Tempfile`
# and passing that into `Zip::ZipFile.open` but I get an error then too
  data = ""
  Zip::ZipFile.open(file) do |zipfile|
    debugger
    zipfile.each do |entry|
      data = entry.file.read(entry.name)
    end
  end
end
```

Before I get to the debugger I'm getting this error

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

the tail end of the contents of `file` look like this

```
?*\xA2\xCD`\x12\xB6\x93\x94\xDE\xF0\xA1\x93E8\xF3o\x11\x02\xF6\xD9.%}\x19\xC7I)\xD9\x0F*\x14\xAB\xC4\x8C\x8A[\xF1\xA5\x98\x19N2qd\x9D\x89\xFD\xA0\x81N\\\x88>E\xF3$X\x1DTBbV<\xF9\xB7\xB5V\xCE9\xEB\x84<\xEB\"\xA4\xCA\x15\xFE\x7F\x01PK\a\b\x15\xAEX\x99\xEA\xF0\x02\x00\xF4\xD9)\x00PK\x01\x02\x14\x00\x14\x00\b\b\b\x00\x97F<D\x15\xAEX\x99\xEA\xF0\x02\x00\xF4\xD9)\x00\e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00KS_Google_Bing-20140128.csvPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00I\x00\x00\x003\xF1\x02\x00\x00\x00"
```

## However, it works from a local zip!

If I pass in the same zip file from my public directory everything works fine.

```
def unzip file
  data = ""
  Zip::ZipFile.open("public/my.zip") do |zipfile| # notice I'm using a local file here instead of the passed in ftp file
    zipfile.each do |entry|
      data = entry.file.read(entry.name)
    end
  end
end
```

And if I look at the contents of the local file `public/my.zip` with code like this:

```
local_file = File.open("public/my.zip")
```

the tail end of `local_file.read` looks like this.

```
FB\xC9ã\u000F\xE1\xEDB*\x8A\xDBT\x94\u0004\xAC;\u05CE\xB7(?*\xA2\xCD`\u0012\xB6\x93\x94\xDE\xF0\xA1\x93E8\xF3o\u0011\u0002\xF6\xD9.%}\u0019\xC7I)\xD9\u000F*\u0014\xABČ\x8A[\xF1\xA5\x98\u0019N2qd\x9D\x89\xFD\xA0\x81N\\\x88>E\xF3$X\u001DTBbV<\xF9\xB7\xB5V\xCE9\xEB\x84<\xEB\"\xA4\xCA\u0015\xFE\u007F\u0001PK\a\b\u0015\xAEX\x99\xEA\xF0\u0002\u0000\xF4\xD9)\u0000PK\u0001\u0002\u0014\u0000\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000\x97F<D\u0015\xAEX\x99\xEA\xF0\u0002\u0000\xF4\xD9)\u0000\e\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000KS_Google_Bing-20140128.csvPK\u0005\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000I\u0000\u0000\u00003\xF1\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

So neither of the look like the raw binary of the zip file, which looks like this on the tail end:

```
38f3 6f11 02f6 d92e 257d 19c7 4929 d90f 2a14 abc4 8c8a 5bf1 a598 194e 3271 649d 89fd a081 4e5c 883e 45f3 2458 1d54 4262 563c f9b7 b556 ce39 eb84 3ceb 22a4 ca15 fe7f 0150 4b07 0815 ae58 99ea f002 00f4 d929 0050 4b01 0214 0014 0008 0808 0097 463c 4415 ae58 99ea f002 00f4 d929 001b 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 004b 535f 476f 6f67 6c65 5f42 696e 672d 3230 3134 3031 3238 2e63 7376 504b 0506 0000 0000 0100 0100 4900 0000 33f1 0200 0000
```

Any help would be AWESOME!!

Comment: i would output your file_names and see what you got, output the filename before you get the file, then output the file contents and see if you're getting something you didn't expect

Comment: @JoeT I've updated with what I'm getting.  I expect binary data that the Zip::ZipFile class can understand.  I don't actually know if that's binary, but I do still get `string contains null byte` error

Comment: ok wait in the second example where you say it works, you have the filename in Zip::ZipFile.open() whereas in the first one giving you the error you have the file contents.  I don't think that will work!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the function Zip::ZipFile.open() expects a filename (not contents), in your second example you are feeding the filename "my.zip" to the function whereas in the example that errors, it appears you're feeding the contents of the file.

I think this answer will work for what you're trying to do here:
[Processing Zip files in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053115/processing-zip-files-in-ruby)

```
Zip::ZipFile.foreach(file) do |entry|
    istream = entry.get_input_stream
    data = istream.read
    #...
end
```