# Unzip binary email attachment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zip, email-attachments

I have a background job in a Rails app which generates a big CSV file and sends it as an attachment to an email message. To manage the size of the email, I'm zipping the CSV before it's attached. This works fine; we have Letter Opener in development and I can open the zipped attachment and read the data. I'm using the "rubyzip" gem to do the zipping.

The trick seems to be testing it. Using rspec, I can verify that the message has an attachment and that the type of the attachment is `application/x-zip-encoded`, which is all good. What I'd like to do is unzip the attachment and validate the data within the test, though, and that's proving more difficult. The attachment is an object of type Mail::Part. If I call the attachment `part`, I can get data from it using `part.body.raw_source`, `part.body.encoded` or `part.decode_body`. (The first and third are identical.) `part.body.encoding` tells me the body is binary. When I try to feed the data to a Zip::InputStream object (using `Zip::InputStream.open(part.body.raw_source)` or any of the other data methods) I get something like `ArgumentError: string contains null byte`.

How can I open this attachment and read its data within rspec? I have a hunch there's a decoding step I need to do in here somewhere.

The errors [look a lot like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21649761/306084), but there's no answer there either.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you want to verify that the gem is doing what it is supposed to do. If this is the case, you should not be doing so. You should not be writing tests to cover another persons library. They should have tests of their own, and if they don't, you can either contribute tests to the project, or find a library that has been tested properly.

Comment: It looks like that, doesn't it. I think my goal is more to verify that the data attached to the email is what's supposed to be attached, and the way to do that is to unzip the data and examine it; I'm getting stuck on the unzip step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here was a little less than ideal, but it works. I had to use the Mail library to write the attachment to a file, then use `Zip::File` to extract the original data and verify it.

```
it 'has a ZIP attachment' do
  additional_fields = ["student_identifiers"]

  expect(message.attachments.size).to eq(1)
  message.attachments.first.tap do |zip|
    expect(zip.content_type).to eq('application/x-zip-compressed')
    tmpfile_name = "tmp/#{zip.filename}"
    File.open(tmpfile_name, "w+b", 0644) { |f| f.write zip.decoded }
    csv = Zip::File.open(tmpfile_name) do |zip_file|
      entry = zip_file.glob('*.csv').first
      entry.get_input_stream.read
    end
    csv.split("\n").tap do |rows|
      expect(rows.size).to be(2)
      rows.each do |row|
        expect(CSV.parse_line(row).size).to eq(dimensions_count)
      end
    end
    File.delete(tmpfile_name)
  end
end
```